# Issue building Linaro GDB for aarch64 on x86_64 host

Tags: linux, arm, arm64, linaro

I downloaded the gdb sources from https://launchpad.net/gdb-linaro/.

I want to build the gdb for aarch64.

As mentioned in README file I set CC to the cross compiler that I have

1. CC=aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc
2. ./configure --host=aarch64

However this doesn't seem right as this sets the target to "aarch64-unknown-none"

And later make fails as below
*** BFD does not support target aarch64-unknown-none.

I am not sure how to pass the correct target name required to cross compile gdb on my system.

Any suggestions will help! :)

Thanks,

MS

Comment: Have you tried `CC=aarch64-linux-gnu-` ?

Comment: I tried this now. But it didn't work (seems configure needs the compiler option). Below is the error in config.log

 70 configure:4201: aarch64-linux-gnu- --version >&5
 71 ./configure: line 4203: aarch64-linux-gnu-: command not found

Comment: Have you installed cross-compiler package (something line `gcc-XXX-aarch64-linux-gnu-YYY`)?

Comment: Yep. Installed the packages for Ubuntu. And the same are available in /usr/bin/ as well..

Answer (score 2):

It seems below does the job.

./configure --host=aarch64-linux-gnu

Thank you for the comments..

BR,

MS